# Basic Unit Test vs. Unit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am working on an MVC project and was wondering whether to use Basic Unit Test or Unit Test, I read articles / explanations about both but can't see much difference between the two. What are the main differences and which one is preferable for a large scale app with DB backend?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The difference between Visual Studio's `Basic Unit Test` item template and `Unit Test` item template is that the latter includes support for `ClassInitialize`, `ClassCleanup`, `TestInitialize` and `TestCleanup` routines allowing you to execute some code before/after the test fixture and some code before/after each unit test. If you don't need such functionality in your unit test you could go wit the basic template which generates the following file:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

Of course you could always add the corresponding routines to a basic unit test if you want to support later this functionality.